# Application entry file does not exist in Electron Builder

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I have a minimal electron app and I am trying to build it (it runs fine). My package.json is

```
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron -r babel-register .",
    "package": "build --dir",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
  },
  // dependencies
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.karmadust.mancuspianconvert",
    "files": [
      "node_modules/**/*"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "assets"
    }
  }
```

When I run `npm run package` I get:

```
Application entry file "main.js" in the "[path-to-project]/dist/mac/myapp.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar" does not exist. Seems like a wrong configuration.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to first build the main electron, you can use `electron-webpack` for that:

*package.json*

```
"scripts": {
    "compile": "electron-webpack",
    "build": "yarn compile && electron-builder" // Compile main first
  },
"electronWebpack": {
    "commonSourceDirectory": "common",
    "main": {
      "sourceDirectory": "main" // The main folder
    },
    "renderer": {
      "sourceDirectory": null // Ignore any renderer build
    },
 }
```

It will create a `main` folder inside your dist with the `main.js` build-in.

You can take a look at [Electron webpack](https://webpack.electron.build/building) documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0):

@Marcelo is right about needing to compile & build your source files. But I'd caution you against `electron-webpack` because [it's become unreliable](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-webpack/issues/428)

Checkout [these boilerplates](https://github.com/sindresorhus/awesome-electron#boilerplates) for some other options, many of which use `electron-builder` under the hood

Answer (score 0):

1st you need to build your electron application with production. You can use the standard ng build command e.g.

```
ng build yourApp --configuration production
```

**Or** if you only have 1 project and working in root

```
ng build --configuration production
```

Now you should have your built code in your dist folder.
e.g.

```
dist/yourApp
```

**Or** your application will just be in dist folder

Now in package.json you need to specify your electron entry file in your built code. If your entry file is called main.js

IN package.json:

```
"main": "dist/yourApp/main.js"
```